# Is it possible to select columns in r based on any value in the column?

Tags: r, select, subset, distinct-values

I want to subset my df to include only columns that include a certain value in any row.

for example, if I have:

```
year = c(1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999)
apple = c(1,4,6,8,9,9,2,4,7,4)
orange = c(7,1,5,5,2,1,7,1,3,8)
banana = c(9,9,4,8,1,3,6,7,5,9)
lemon = c(8,3,3,3,2,5,6,7,2,4)
df = data.frame(year,apple,orange,banana,lemon)

df
```

I want to select only the columns that have a 9 anywhere in the column so that my df would become only include the apple and banana columns.

Is this possible? All the answers I've found so far only enable selecting columns based on the column name, but I want to select based on cell values within the column. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can pass a function in `select` within `where` - check whether the column is numeric and if that is numeric, check whether there are `any` value equal to 9.  In addition can change the `any(.x ==9)` to `9 %in% .x`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  select(where(~is.numeric(.x) && any(.x == 9)))
```

-output

```
 apple banana
1      1      9
2      4      9
3      6      4
4      8      8
5      9      1
6      9      3
7      2      6
8      4      7
9      7      5
10     4      9
```

Comment: So `where` is necessary with select to quasi "filter" columns. Interesting that there is no `filter` for columns?!

Comment: @TarJae in `dplyr`, `select` does the selection of columns, whereas `filter` does the subsetting of rows.  In `subset` from `base R`, also, we have `subset` and `select` for row/column.  whereas `Filter` in `base R`, does the selection of columns if it is a data.frame

Comment: @TarJae according to `?where` `where() takes a function and returns all variables for which the function returns TRUE:`

Answer (score 3):

`base R` option using `Filter`:

```
Filter(function(x) any(x == 9), df)
```

Output:

```
   apple banana
1      1      9
2      4      9
3      6      4
4      8      8
5      9      1
6      9      3
7      2      6
8      4      7
9      7      5
10     4      9
```

Answer (score 3):

This one is long and too verbose and the perfect answer is already provided by @akrun.
Therefore here an alternative approach:
What we do here is `mutate` `across` each column except `year` check if they contain a `9` if so then put the name of column to a new column called `x`,

then use `any_of` with `select`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(-year, ~case_when(. == 9 ~ cur_column()), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>%
  unite(x, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ' ') %>% 
  select(any_of(x))


   banana apple
1       9     1
2       9     4
3       4     6
4       8     8
5       1     9
6       3     9
7       6     2
8       7     4
9       5     7
10      9     4
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably we can use `colMeans` like below, where the mean value should be non-zero if there exists at least one `9` in the column

```
> df[colMeans(df == 9) > 0]
   apple banana
1      1      9
2      4      9
3      6      4
4      8      8
5      9      1
6      9      3
7      2      6
8      4      7
9      7      5
10     4      9
```